# SPI DAC not changing from initial value

Tags: spi, dac, mbed

I've written a test program which outputs 255 to the TLV5606 DAC via SPI, all which works as expected.

I then tried extending the program to update the value to 512, after a 5 second delay.

```
#include "mbed.h"

SPI spi(p5, p6, p7); // mosi, miso, sclk
DigitalOut fs(p8);


int main() {
    fs = 0;

    uint16_t fixed = 0x4000;
    uint16_t value = 255;

    value = value << 2;
    uint16_t final = fixed | value;


    spi.format(16,1);
    spi.frequency(100000);



    fs = 1;

    fs = 0;

    spi.write(final);



    fs = 1;

    wait(5000);



    value = 512;
    value = value << 2;
    final = fixed | value;

    fs = 0;

    spi.write(final);



    fs = 1;





}
```

Measuring with my oscilloscope, I can see that the initial voltage is ~1.01v, which is expected, however there is no subsequent change, after 5 seconds, or longer. I tried brings fs high and then low again as well, and this made no difference. Any thoughts on what's happening?

Here is what the scope shows for the first transmission (fs, and data):

[image]

Comment: Why don't you put your scope on the SPI bus and check what pattern is being transmitted?

Comment: @Oldfart, I'm having trouble using the logic analyser. Is there another way?

Comment: My method is to look at two signals at a time. (As my scope has only two inputs) Start with CS (=trigger falling edge) and clock. If that looks good use CS and MOSI or clock and MOSI. That should allow you to analyze the data bits especially if you have only two or three data bursts as in your case. That all assume a digital scope :-)

Comment: @Oldfart, Ok, I'll try using the scope's analog inputs. I'm using the Analog Discover 2, and at the moment, nothing is showing. Can you advise what base, rate, etc. parameters I should use, considering the SPI frequency is set to 100000 (as shown in the code above)?

Comment: @Oldfart, please see edit.

Comment: Nothing seems to appear for the second transmission.

Comment: WOW! That looks like you got some serious problems with your data line. I suggest you check your system (power supplies) and give us a diagram of what is connected where during these measurements. Also indicate where your your scope ground is. It is late here so I might not be back for a while.

Comment: @Oldfart, that is what I thought, but the initial value always seems to be correct, I've tried a range of values, so maybe it's a problem with how I've measured it?